# The page you are looking for is not found error message - nginx

Tags: nginx, centos

I installed nginx and it works fine.
now I want to create a directory and put my file inside it, what I want:

```
myip/index/index.html
```

this is config file of nginx:

```
 server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  _;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
        }

        location /index{
                root /home/sunyar/data/www;
                index index.html;
        }
        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }
    }
```

this is my directory and I find it with this command:

```
pwd

/home/sunyar/data/www
```

inside it there a `index.html` file.

but when I enter `http://192.168.15.9/index/index.html` url it return this content:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the error log. With your current configuration, there should be an entry describing the issue.

The `root` directive operates by concatenating its value with the URI, so the file is being searched for at: `/home/sunyar/data/www/index/index.html`.

To remove the extra `/index/` you will need to use `alias`.

For example:

```
location /index {
    alias /home/sunyar/data/www;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) for details.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53152552/permission-denied-to-custom-direcotry-nginx