# Permission denied to custom direcotry nginx

Tags: nginx, centos

I created a directory:

```
data/www
```

inside it there is a index.html file.

I set this permission to this directory:

```
sudo chmod -R g+w data/
```

this is my nginx config:

```
server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    listen       [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name  _;
    root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

    # Load configuration files for the default server block.
    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

    location / {
    }

    location /index{
            alias /home/sunyar/data/www/;
            index index.html;
    }
    error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /40x.html {
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
    }
}
```

but I got `403 Forbidden` message on my browser:

```
http://192.168.15.9/index.html
```

my error message inside log file:

```
2018/11/05 13:58:23 [error] 13102#0: *5 open() "/home/sunyar/data/www/.html" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 192.168.101.148, server: _, request: "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1", host: "192.168.15.9"
```

Comment: Why do you need `location /index`? The `/index.html` URI can be processed in the `location /` block with `root /home/sunyar/data/www;`.

Comment: this is a test url. I just my load index.html file. that's it.

Comment: Your current configuration aliases `/index.html` to `/home/sunyar/data/www/.html` (as the error message confirms). You need to use `root` instead of `alias` to find your file (this is the exact opposite of your previous question).

Comment: ok, now I changed it to: `root /home/sunyar/data/www/;` and I enter this url: `http://192.168.15.9/index.html` but I got this error: `2018/11/05 14:35:47 [error] 13303#0: *1 open() "/home/sunyar/data/www/index.html" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 192.168.101.148, server: _, request: "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1", host: "192.168.15.9"`

Comment: That is a permissions problem. Check that the Nginx worker has access to the file and directories above it.